# "Argument of length zero" in R

Tags: r

[I have a data like this and i dont know how to make plot with it, so i wirte a script to change to another form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwgfC.png)

And here is the result of dput(head(e1)):

```
structure(list(lon = c(-26.583, -26.25, -26.417, -67.25, -67.25, 
-67.417), lat = c(-59.083, -58.417, -58.417, -55.917, -55.75, 
-55.75), pre1 = c(105.4, 106.3, 106.6, 73.1, 68.7, 70.2)), .Names = c("lon", 
"lat", "pre1"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The first column is longitude and the second one is latitude, the third one is precipitation value of this point. What i want to do is make a map by this data, but i dont know how to deal with this format, so i want to change it to three matrix: one for longitude,one for latitude, one for precipitation, and than i can use the function image.plot(lon,lat,pre1) to make a map of precipitation.

This is my script:

```
rerange<-function(e1) {
latq<-sort(e1$lat,decreasing = T)
latq<-as.matrix(latq)
latq1<-unique.matrix(latq)
lonq<-sort(e1$lon)
lonq<-as.matrix(lonq)
lonq1<-unique.matrix(lonq)
lenlon<-length(lonq1)
lenlat<-length(latq1)
finalq<-matrix(0,lenlon,lenlat)
for (i in 1:lenlat) {
  for (j in 1:lenlon) {
      finalq[i,j]<-e1$pre1[e1$lon == lonq1[j] & e1$lat == latq1[i] ]
    }
  }
return(finalq)
}
```

But it return a error like this:

```
Error in finalq[i, j] <- e1$pre1[e1$lon == lonq1[j] & e1$lat == latq1[i]] : 
replacement has length zero
```

I have try other ways, however I am unable to figure out the error.How i can fix it? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To share data in the `r` tag we ask that you use `dput()` rather than screenshots. You can find more info on this by hovering your pointer over the `r` tag.

Comment: My guess is different that the other guesses, but I don't see any point in enumerating all the guesses. I endorse Hack-R's suggestion to post `dput( head( e1))` so we can actually _know_ what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the help. And sorry for providing the unclear information. Its my first time asking question here. And i will add more information about it and try my best to make it clear. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, checking out your data, I think this is more or less what you are after:

```
# create the dataframe
df <- structure(list(lon = c(-26.583, -26.25, -26.417, -67.25, -67.25, 
                   -67.417), lat = c(-59.083, -58.417, -58.417, -55.917, -55.75, 
                                     -55.75), pre1 = c(105.4, 106.3, 106.6, 73.1, 68.7, 70.2)), .Names = c("lon", 
                                                                                                           "lat", "pre1"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

# change from long to wide format
test <- reshape(df, timevar = "lat", idvar = "lon", direction = "wide")
# turn missing values into zeros
test[is.na(test)] <- 0
# use lon for rownames
rownames(test) <- test[, 1]
# drop the first column
test <- test[,c(2:5)]
# load stringr library
library(stringr)
# drop text from column names
colnames(test) <- str_replace(colnames(test), "pre1.", "")
# put rownames and colnames into increasing order
test <- test[order(rownames(test), decreasing = TRUE), order(colnames(test), decreasing = TRUE)]
test
# load the plotting library
library(fields)
# make the plot
image.plot(as.numeric(rownames(test)), as.numeric(colnames(test)),  as.matrix(test))
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: How can you possibly claim to have fixed his code when you have no clue what he was trying to accomplish?

Comment: I guess that the person who asked the question will be able to judge that once they see the output. Once more information is provided about the endgame, we can take it from there. I will gladly delete/edit my answer when the person asking decides this is not what they intended to obtain.

Comment: Thanks for you advice. I have try the way you said, but still not working. And sorry i didnt make it clear, i have add more information about this issue.

Comment: @Hack-R You were right, my original answer was not solving the issue at all. Now it should be better.

Comment: @ira Thank you sooooo much. I've got what i want. You advice is so amazing, its very simple just use " reshape()" function, i have a lot to learn. And there is a little mistake i think when i run this code : order(rownames(test)  should change into order(as.numeric(rownames(test))),  otherwise it will get the wrong order. I appreciate you help, thanks again.

Comment: @Hack-R I have got what i want, thanks for you help and advice :)